# Backdate Orders? Change date on manual orders

Tags: orders

When creating an order, is there anyway to select the date when the order was made.

As some orders taken offline, we want to add back into the sytem, with the correct date, so they show on the reports.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way with vanilla Magento. There may be a way via some module that exists.

Programmatically if you would like to change the date of an order you can do so via:

```
$orderId = '100000001'; //change this to your increment id
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

$order->setCreatedAt('2013-01-01 04:00:00'); //or whatever date you wish
$order->save();
```

Comment: I am looking to maybe have a datepicker in the create order in the admin for that - Any idea where to start

Comment: @philwinkle Thanks for this bro.  Hey do you know if there are any other dates that would be important to modify as well?  The order status entry comes to mind - this might be a good place for a cannonical answer on all the dates needing modified when backdating an order.

Comment: @philwinkle hi i use this code ans set `date = '2016-04-27 16:00:00';` but in my order it show me the 'Apr 27, 2016 12:00:00 PM' how can i fix this?

Comment: HI Eleven11 , have you find any solution for this, if you have please update the answer